# How to show that $[c_i, d_i] \subset [a_i- \lambda, b_i + \lambda]$?

Tags: real-analysis, diffeomorphism

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 152, it is given that

[image]

However, I cannot see how do we we have that $[c_i, d_i] \subset [a_i- \lambda, b_i + \lambda]$. I mean I have tried forming counterexamples, but every case what obeying the above condition, but still I cannot see the logical implication.

So, why do we have $[c_i, d_i] \subset [a_i- \lambda, b_i + \lambda]$, and how can we show it ?

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: What's in figure 18.1?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "$1/N$ is less than the small of $\delta$ and $\lambda$.",  In the figure below, note that the interval $[a_i - 1/N,a_i + 1/N]$ contains both neighboring elements of the form $m/N$.  That is, 
$$
a_i - \lambda < a_i - 1/N \leq c_i 
$$
and similarly,
$$
b_i + \lambda > b_i + 1/N \geq d_i 
$$

**Edit:**

Note that the maximality of $c_i$ contradicts with that if $c_i + 1/N \leq a_i$, so we have $c_i \leq a_i \leq c_i + 1/N$.

Comment: If $a_i$ had the form $m/N$, then $c_i$ would be clearly $(m-1) / N$, but I still cannot see why $a_i - 1/N \leq c_i$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas in fact: in that case, we would have $c_i = a_i = m/N$

Comment: Well, I did not noticed the equality in $\leq$, so you are correct.

Comment: @onurcanbektas look at the figure: the distance between two consecutive points of the form $m/N$ is $1/N$.  If $a_i$ lies between them, then the distance to the closest such point must be *at most* $1/N$.

Comment: Do we know that $c_i + 1/N \geq a_i$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Yes, that's what I'm saying. If $c_i + 1/N \leq a_i$, then $c_i$ fails to be "the largest number [of the form $m/N$] for which $c_i \leq a_i$".

Comment: I sometimes do now process what I'm reading, sorry; you are right, thanks.

Comment: I hope the edit is OK, I just wanted to put the content of the comment into the answer.

Comment: @onurcanbektas that's fine. Glad it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $c_i$ is the largest number of the form $\frac{m}{N}$ such that $c_i \leqslant a_i$. So if we take any larger number of that form, e.g. $\frac{m+1}{N}$, it must be larger than $a_i$, i.e. $a_i < \frac{m+1}{N} = c_i + \frac{1}{N}$. Now since $\frac{1}{N} \leqslant \lambda$, we have that

$$a_i - \lambda \leqslant a_i - \frac{1}{N} < c_i.$$

In an analogous way we prove that $d_i < b_i + \lambda$, which gives $[c_i, d_i] \subsetneq [a_i - \lambda, b_i + \lambda]$.